# Validar datos y mostrar alertas bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

He hecho un formulario bootstrap en un modal, que cuando le doy a un botón submit "guardar", se me guardan los valores de los campos en la base de datos. Hasta aqui todo bien.

Me gustaría que antes de enviarse los valores,  los campos se validaran, para mirara si un campo esta vacio o hay algo que no quiera como poner, como una edad en negativo.

Tengo comprendido que toda la gente utiliza jquery pero para mi es un lio del copón, pero si hay que hacerlo de esa forma, adelante.
Pues nada,  os pregunto como algo que se validen los campos y  que salgan esas alertas arriba del modal tan bonitas de bootstrap.

Aqui os dejo mi formulario

```
        <div class="modal" id="nuevoUsu" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labellebdy="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4>Nuevo Contacto</h4>                       
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                   <form action="insertar.php" method="GET">                    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre"></input>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="edad">Edad:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="edad" name="edad" type="text" placeholder="Edad"></input>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="direccion">Direccion:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="direccion" name="direccion" type="text" placeholder="Direccion"></input>
                        </div>

                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Salvar">
                   </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Perdón si ofendo a alguien por mi poca capacidad de programar, pero a mi edad ya es complicado aprender.

Comment: tengo este `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">`. Gracias por comentar Sebastián.

Comment: voy a mirar, un momento porfavor. Vale, listo, pone **Bootstrap v3.3.6 (http://getbootstrap.com)**. Gracias Sebastián

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primero para validar que solo se ingresen números puedes hacer lo siguiente con javascript , se usa directamente en el input de edad así

```js
 function solonumeros(e)
                    {
         var key = window.event ? e.which : e.keyCode;
                        if(key < 48 || key > 57)
                            e.preventDefault();
                    }
```

```html
<label>Edad</label>
<input id="edad" type="text" onkeypress="solonumeros(event);">
```

Ese código no permite que ingrese caracteres y letras demás. Entonces para validar depués solo tienes que preguntar si lo ingresado es menor a 0 de esta forma, ademas de validar los demás campos:

```js
function validaCampos(){

var nombre = $("#nombre").val();
var edad = $("#edad").val();
var direccion = $("#direccion").val();
//validamos campos
if($.trim(nombre) == ""){
toastr.error("No ha ingresado Nombre","Aviso!");
    return false;
}
                   if($.trim(edad) == ""){
toastr.error("No ha ingresado Edad","Aviso!");
    return false;
}

            if(edad < 0){
toastr.error("Mínimo permitido 0","Aviso!");
    return false;
}
if($.trim(direccion) == ""){
toastr.error("No ha ingresado Dirección","Aviso!");
    return false;
}

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script>

//importamos configuraciones de toastr
toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": false,
  "debug": false,
  "newestOnTop": false,
  "progressBar": false,
  "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
  "preventDuplicates": false,
  "onclick": null,
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "5000",
  "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
}


</script>
<form action="insertar.php" method="GET" onsubmit="return validaCampos();">                    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre"></input>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="edad">Edad:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="edad" name="edad" type="text" placeholder="Edad"></input>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="direccion">Direccion:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="direccion" name="direccion" type="text" placeholder="Direccion"></input>
                        </div>

                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Salvar">
                   </form>
```

Con este código podrás validar antes de enviar , explico entonces de que trata la validación anterior
cuando digo `$.trim(nombre)` en esta linea `$.trim` quita todas los espacios dentro del campo entonces aunque presionen la tecla espaciador y envíen, va a validar que este en blanco el input. Entonces cuando retorno false hago que el formulario no se envie hasta que la todo este correcto. Por ultimo hice usar los mensajes que entrega la libreria de toastr que es para mostrar mensajes de validaciones de forma mas gráfica. Ojala te sirva Saludos.

> NOTA: $.trim() es de jquery, así que necesitas esa librería para poder
>   usarlo.

Comment: madre miaaaaa, usted es un crack!!!! MUCHÍSIMAS GRACIAS!! :) me acaba de hacer un dia muy feliz

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu mejor opción es utilizar bootstrapValidator (http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-usage)

Utiliza jQuery, así que tendrás que incluirlo, pero es un solución fácil y elegante.

Simplemente tienes que definir en cada campo (identificado por el atributo `name`) las reglas que quieres que cumplan. Te permite también utilizar reglas personalizadas.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#nuevoUsu').modal() ;

$('#nuevoUsu').bootstrapValidator({            
        fields: {
           nombre: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'El nombre es obligatorio'
                    }
                }
            },
            edad: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'La edad es obligatoria'
                    },
                    integer: {
                    message: 'Debe introducir un valor entero'
                }
                }
            },
            direccion: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'La dirección es obligatoria'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>

<div class="modal" id="nuevoUsu" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labellebdy="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4>Nuevo Contacto</h4>                       
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                   <form action="insertar.php" method="GET">                    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre"></input>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="edad">Edad:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="edad" name="edad" type="text" placeholder="Edad"></input>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="direccion">Direccion:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="direccion" name="direccion" type="text" placeholder="Direccion"></input>
                        </div>

                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Salvar">
                   </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Aquí una lista de validaciones:
http://bootstrapvalidator.votintsev.ru/validators/

Answer (score 1):

Después de buscar un poco me encontré este plugin, el validator for Bootstrap, fácil de implementar aunque depende de jquery... adjunto ejemplo de codigo para que lo puedas examinar...

http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!